# Can I use variable expansion in Gitlab CI variables block?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

My git commit tags are in format `@org/service@v1.0.0`. In Gitlab CI this can be accessed via predefined variable `$CI_COMMIT_TAG`. Is it possible to extract only the version number - `v1.0.0` in this case - and make it available to jobs through `variables` block?

Something like this:

```
variables:
  TAG: $(echo $CI_COMMIT_TAG | sed "s/.*@//")
```

The above sadly doesn't work, the TAG variable does not exist in consecutive jobs.

Also, please not that I'm *not* able to define TAG in the `before_script` as it comes from external file via `include` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot invoke `sed` or other utilities/shell features in a `variables:` declaration.

> Also, please not that I'm not able to define TAG in the before_script as it comes from external file via include directive.

You can always override specific elements of jobs, even when they come from `include:`

```yaml
included_job:
  before_script:
    - echo "overridden before_script"
    - export TAG="$(echo $CI_COMMIT_TAG | sed "s/.*@//")"
    # ...
```

Another option is to pass the variable through `artifacts:reports:dotenv`. All jobs that receive this artifact will have the variables created in the job's dotenv  file.

```
create-tag:
  stage: .pre
  script:
    - TAG="$(echo $CI_COMMIT_TAG | sed "s/.*@//")"
    - echo "TAG=${TAG}" > variables.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: variables.env
```